Why does "pos" disappear in Perl's string eval?
This short perl script
my $var='$array', $val;

$val='val'; eval("push(\@{$var},$val)"); print"@{$array}[0]\n";
$val='pos'; eval("push(\@{$var},$val)"); print"@{$array}[1]\n";
$val='fun'; eval("push(\@{$var},$val)"); print"@{$array}[2]\n";


results to
val

fun


Can anybody explain me, why val and fun got pushed on array, but pos does not?
I would expect that any value would be pushed by the eval-statement.

pos is a function, and strings should be quoted ie qq($val) instead of just $val. I assume this is an exercise in eval and not the actual code that engages in poor programming practices.

I started writing an answer to explain what went wrong here, but I gave up. Basically your code contains mistakes and faulty premises. Don't try to access an arrays namespace via a string. If you want to use strings, use a hash. Hash keys were meant to be strings. E.g. push @{ $arrays{$key} }, $val, and don't use eval.

And if you want to print something to debug, use Data::Dumper: use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@array; And always use use strict; use warnings; when you write code, otherwise you risk making simple mistakes.

First of all, ALWAYS use use strict; use warnings; or equivalent. It would have caught all of your errors.

These are the strings you are building and passing to eval:
push(@{array},val);
push(@{array},pos);
push(@{array},fun);

Without use strict;, these are equivalent to the following:
push( @array, "val" );
push( @array, pos() );
push( @array, "fun" );

@{array} is a weird and undocumented way of writing @array.
pos is a builtin function related to regex matching. In this program, it's returning undef. This gets stringified to the empty string (and warns) when printing.
val and fun are equivalent to "val" and "fun" because they couldn't possibly mean anything else.  (They are "barewords".)

You want to evaluate the following code:
push( @array, $val )

To generate that string, you'd want
"push( \@$var, \$val )"   # Or: sprintf( 'push( @%s, $val )', $var )

So using eval EXPR, this would look like this:
eval( "push( \@$var, \$val )" )

You were missing the second \. (You also had extra curlies. These actually work, but it's an undocumented feature best avoided.)
This is fragile and dangerous, and using eval EXPR is completely unnecessary here. You could use the following:
{
   no strict qw( refs );
   push( @$var, $val );
}

But there's a reason we ask Perl to prevent us from doing this by adding use strict; to every program: It's a really really bad practice. You should use a hash instead.
my %arrays;
push @{ $arrays{ $var } }, $val;


The second eval is evaluating the string 'push(@{$array},pos'. posis a builtin function that returns something related to regex matching. As no regex was used yet in the script, the function pos returns an undefined value. The undefined value is printed as an empty string.
The barewords "val" and "fun" are not builtin functions. Therefore they are conidered as plain strings.
